# Multisite and plugins options

Tags: multisite, options

I need more information about `get_site_option()`, `update_site_option()` and `add_site_option()`.
In codex they say it's the same as single install except that in multisite, it returns the network-wide option.

Ok but I get confused on the this point : does it mean once network-wide option is set this option is the same in all sites? Or is it overriden per each site?

I mean if I do this :

```
 update_site_option('option_group', 'default_options());// default_options() returns an array of default options
```

Where will it save datas? And will each site get its own values for options after?

It's quite unclear for me any hint will be cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back when Multisite first appeared, there were multiple *blogs* in a single *site*. The `*_site_option` functions are from that older Multisite era.

Now in current Multisite you have multiple *sites* in a *network*, so the meaning of "site" has made a confusing change.

In the context of these functions, think of them as *network* functions and it may make more sense. They create and update options which are not associated to a particular site in your network, but are global to the whole network.

If you want unique, per-site options, use the regular `add_option`, `update_option`, and `get_option`.